# Calculate Content-Length in HTTP Header

Tags: html, header, content-length

Is this method correct? Or do I have to include "\r\n" to the header and not calculate its content length?

```
String s;
String h;
h = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n";
s = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n<html>";
s += "<br>";
[...]
s += "<br></html>";
client.print(h + "Content-Length: " + s.bytelength() + s);
```

Comment: Or do I have to include "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\r\n"

Comment: Just noticed the String does not provide bytelength - can I use length instead, or is there a String equivalent to bytelength?